# Constructing a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, interpolation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Terms of a Sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198915/terms-of-a-sequence)

Construct a sequence of interpolating values $Y_n \text{ to }f(1 + \sqrt{10})$, where $f(x) = (1 + x^2)^{-1}$ for 
$-5 \leq x \leq 5$, as follows: For each n = 1,2, ... ,10, let $h = \frac{10} {n}$ and $Y_n = P_n(1 + \sqrt{10})$,
where $P_n(x)$ is the interpolating polynomial for f(x) at the nodes $x_0^n, x_1^n,…,x_n^n$ and 
$x_j^n= -5 + jh$, for each j  = 0, 1,2, ... ,n.

What would my sequence be?
I am unsure as to what my x's would be. Every x has the formula of -5+jh but I am unsure what I would plug in for my i and j