# Terms of a Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Construct a sequence of interpolating values $Y_n,  to,f(1 + \sqrt{10})$, where $f(x) = (1 + X^2)^{-1}$ for 
$-5 \leq X \leq 5$, as follows: For each n = 1,2, ... ,10, let $h = \frac{10} {n}$

$x_j^n= -5 + jh$, for each j  = 0, 1,2, ... ,n. 
What would my sequence be exactly.
I have come up with something but it seems incorrect.

The first term would be : $-5+0*\frac{10} {1}$

The second ther would be : $-5+1*\frac{10} {2}$

And so forth. But I have a feeling that this is incorrect.

Comment: what kind of interpolation are you using?

Comment: Lagrange interpolation / Neville's Method but that is the easy part. Once I figure out what my x-values are then the rest is quite simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as if you are being asked to use $n$ subintervals (therefore, $n+1$ points) to interpolate the function $f$ on $[-5,5]$. Since the width of the interval is $10$, the width of each subinterval is $h=\frac{10}n$. The mesh for $n$ intervals consists of the points $x_j^n=-5+jh=-5+j\frac{10}n$ for $j=0,1,2,\dots,n$.

For a particular $n$, compute $f(x_j^n)$ for $j=0,1,2,\dots,n$ and interpolate to get $f(1+\sqrt{10})$.

For example, if $n=4$, use the $x$ values $\{-5,-2.5,0,2.5,5\}$ and the $y$ values $\{f(-5),f(-2.5),f(0),f(2.5),f(5)\}$.

The interpolating polynomial is $1-\frac{129}{754}x^2+\frac{2}{377}x^4$ and when that is evaluated at $1+\sqrt{10}$, we get $-\frac1{754}(21+82\sqrt{10})\approx-.3717596394$, which is the fourth value your book gives.

Comment: Ok here is the answer that is in the back of my book: The first 10 terms of the sequences

Comment: The first 10 terms of the sequence are $.038462, .333671, .116605, -.371760, -.0548919, .605935, .190249, -.513353, -.0668173, .448335 \text{ and } f(1+ \sqrt{10})=.0545716$

Comment: As you can see these 10 terms are in reality the y-values or f(x). They have been plugged into the equation $(1+x^{2})^{-1}$

Comment: @math101: how are you getting negative values for $(1+x^2)^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Yes you are definitely correct. This was the answer provided in the back of the book. This is quite interesting

Comment: @math101: The answers in the back of the book are for the interpolated values of $f(1+\sqrt{10})$ using $n=1,2,3,\dots,10$. For $n=1$ you are only using $f(-5)=\frac1{26}$ and $f(5)=\frac1{26}$, so the value of $f(1+\sqrt{10})=\frac1{26}$.

Comment: Thanks @robjohn I really appreciate the time you took to help me. I was sooo utterly lost. Thanks you are awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

You want $11$ equally spaced points from $-5$ to $5,$ which are all the integers:  $-5, -4, -3, \ldots ,5$.  $h$ should be one value, here $1$, which is the spacing of the points.  It should be the length of the interval $(10)$ divided by the number of spaces $(10)$.  I don't know where you got $h=\frac{10}n.$  So it should be $-5+0*1, -5+1*1, \ldots -5+10*1$

Comment: Your answer seems correct but then it doesn't match the answer I have found unless the answer is incorrect. I wonder

Comment: $h=\frac{10} {n}$ was given in the question

Comment: @math101:  that is fine, but it should not be "For each $n=1,2,\ldots ,10$ because $n$ doesn't vary.  Maybe this fragment should come before $x_j^n=-5+jh$

Comment: For some reason it doesnt match the answers given in my book. For some reason the question was worded unclearly and its hard to put the pieces together